# decisive trees to pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tensorflow

all day trying to implement decisive trees on the titanic database using TensorFlow.

```
fc = tf.feature_column
CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS = ['Pclass', 'Sex', 'SibSp', 'Parch', 'Embarked']
NUMERIC_COLUMNS = ['Age', 'Fare']

   def one_hot_cat_column(feature_name, vocab):
     return tf.feature_column.indicator_column(tf.feature_column.\
             categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(feature_name,vocab))
feature_columns = []
for feature_name in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS:
  # Need to one-hot encode categorical features.
  vocabulary = train[feature_name].unique()
  feature_columns.append(one_hot_cat_column(feature_name, vocabulary))
  
  for feature_name in NUMERIC_COLUMNS:
     feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.\
                           numeric_column(feature_name,dtype=tf.float32))
```

everywhere only this method of implementation. this block implements the "one-hot encoder". How to convert the result after these manipulations into a Pandas table? Needed for easy viewing and better understanding of how these lines work

Comment: how about starting with `pd.DataFrame(feature_columns)` and see what comes out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose y_test is your predictions and y is the columns specified for submission, then execute:
`df = pd.DataFrame(data=y_test,columns=['y'])`
Columns refer to the column name and then simply do `df.to_csv` to convert your predictions dataframe in csv type file and submit.

Comment: but there are no predictions. This is the preparation of input values for the implementation of decision trees for tensorflow